# How to run all tests in junit

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to learn junit testing in eclipse and i have tried to start off with something simple. I wrote a basic program with 2 methods, an add and subtract method which both take 2 arguments. So I tried testing the add function only, with a test that looked like this

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class addtest {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        class1 calc = new class1();
        int expected = 7;
        int actual = class1.add(3, 4);
        assertEquals("adding 3 and 4 ", expected, actual);
        expected = 15;
        actual = class1.add(5, 10);
        assertEquals("adding 5 and 10 ", expected, actual);
    }
}
```

and it was working as i wanted.

But then when i tried to implement the second test for subtraction, i noticed that it never seemed to test that section. I even tried having a second test method in case my subtraction method was incorrect. This is what i have for my latest test.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class addtest {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        class1 calc = new class1();
        int expected = 7;
        int actual = class1.add(3, 4);
        assertEquals("adding 3 and 4 ", expected, actual);
        expected = 15;
        actual = class1.add(5, 10);
        assertEquals("adding 5 and 10 ", expected, actual);
    }

    public void testMinus() {
        class1 calc = new class1();
        int expected = 0;
        int actual = class1.add(12, 4);
        assertEquals("subtracting 4 from 12", expected, actual);
    }

}
```

I noticed that the test testMinus never does anything, whether the assert is true of not. Is there something wrong with my implementation? I have tried running the source folder as a junit test already, nothing was fixed.

Thanks a lot for any help

EDIT: I tried commenting out the first test, so that my test function has only testMinus inside it, and now it is testing the second method. Is there a reason the program stops testing after going through the first method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `@Test` above your minusTest method also. It looks like

```
@Test
public void testMinus() {
    class1 calc = new class1();
    int expected = 0;
    int actual = class1.add(12, 4);
    assertEquals("subtracting 4 from 12", expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I assumed the @Test was not important because of the appearance of the text in eclipse. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: For future reference, the reason the text looks different in Eclipse is because lines beginning with `@` are annotations, which are typically extra pieces of information that help with compilation/analysis but aren't always actually compiled. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Comment: Every test you run should be annotated with @Test annotation.

Comment: if this solved your problem, then accept this as answer so that others don't visit solved question.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
@Test
public void testMinus() {
    class1 calc = new class1();
    int expected = 0;
    int actual = calc.add(12, 4); // Issue with current implementation, method should be called with instance of a class.
    assertEquals("subtracting 4 from 12", expected, actual);
}
```

`

All Junit tests should be annotated with with @Test.

Comment: thank you, just to expand on this question, in eclipse i see runs, failures and errors in the junit testing menu. Obviously the runs and failures are self explanatory, but what would be an example of a failure?

Comment: If test fails cause of any assertion or any other issue then it will show you that testcase as failed. Failure will show you number of failed testcases. Here is example with ur existing code:
 @Test
 public void testMinus() {
     class1 calc = new class1();
     int expected = 0;
     int actual = calc.add(12, 4);
     assertEquals("subtracting 4 from 12", 4, actual);

Comment: Btw, I see that you have issue with int actual = class1.add(12, 4); statement. Method should be called with instance of an class which is calc in this case.